# Can you please specify that how much apple paying for per app downloads

Tags: ios-appstore

Can you please specify that how much apple pays per app downloads.

I want to know that how much amount apple pays for app download/device.

I know, it's not a programming related question, but I don't know where to ask it. I posted a question on the Apple support forum, but got no reply.

Thanks in advance for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the price of your app.

For each sale, Apple charges a [30% tax](http://www.businessinsider.com/apples-ios-tax-2013-4) on the price paid by the user.